# How to use Unsigned char* string as a normal char* string

Tags: c, string, encryption, openssl

I am not able to use the decrypted string. Example I want to copy the decrypted string to other string. If I try to copy using strcpy I get error in decrypt statement . I works fine if I only prints the decrypted string. I got the correct decypted string. But issues start when I try to use the decrypted string for some purpose. what may be the issue ?
I am using the openssl encrytion and decryption.

```
 void kdcStep3(connection_info *connection, char msg[128]) {

printf(KCYN " %s" RESET "\n",connection->username);

char myUsername[50];
char myPassword[50];
puts(msg);

strcpy(myUsername, strtok(connection->username, " "));
strcpy(myPassword, strtok(NULL, " "));
puts(myPassword);

  /* A 256 bit key */
  unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)myPassword;

  /* A 128 bit IV */
  unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456";


  /* Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
   * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, dependant on the
   * algorithm and mode
   */
  unsigned char ciphertext[128];

  /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
  unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

  int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

  /* Initialise the library */
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  OPENSSL_config(NULL);

  /* Encrypt the plaintext */
  ciphertext_len = strlen(msg);

  /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
  printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
  //BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

  /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
  decryptedtext_len = decrypt(msg, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
    decryptedtext);

  /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
  decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

  /* Show the decrypted text */
  printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
  printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_cleanup();
  ERR_free_strings();


puts((const char*)decryptedtext);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If decrypted text prints correctly by `puts`, it means that it has been processed correctly. Inability to use it must come from the way in which you pass it back to the caller. Since `decryptedtext` buffer is local to your function, you cannot simply return it to the caller. You need to either copy it into a block of memory that has been `malloc`-ed, like this

```
unsigned char *kdcStep3(connection_info *connection, char msg[128]) {
    ...
    unsigned char *res = malloc(decryptedtext_len+1);
    memcpy(res, decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len);
    res[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

or change the API to take `decryptedtext` as an argument, like this:

```
size_t kdcStep3(connection_info *connection, char msg[128], unsigned char decryptedtext[128]) {
    ...
    return decryptedtext_len;
}
```

Comment: The issue is if I do something like strtok(res, " "), in your first suggestion. I get error `140555248260768:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:`

Comment: @tarun14110 How can `strtok` return an error like that? Is there a step in between that I am missing?

Comment: thats what I am not able to get. Not only strtok, whenever I use decryptedtext like splitting it, I get same error. I amgetting segmentation fault on `printf("%c", decryptedtext[1]);`, if this can help.

Comment: the issue is may be because of unsigned char* type of decryptedtext ?

Comment: @tarun14110 This issue is definitely not because of the type of `decryptedtext`. Signed and unsigned `char` always have identical representation. What changes is the conversion of individual values to integer: 255 stored in a signed char would become `-1` when promoted to an `int`, while the same value stored in an `unsigned char` would remain 255. That's the only difference. Are you sure that you get this error at the time you split it, or is the error already there after a prior call, but it gets printed when you flush `stdout` by writing `\n` into it?